# Editable year planner

Tags: windows-xp, calendar

Can anyone recommend any freeware/shareware for creating an editable year planner? - or just a regular calendar program which has a mechanism for displaying a whole year at a time.

**EDIT:** Ok, I'll even consider paying for the software as it looks like this may be a hard to find item.

**EDIT:** It looks like there is a gap in the market here if anyone feels like writing some shareware... With super large monitors (1920x1200 and up) becoming ever cheaper, editable year planners are now a very viable product... I'll volunteer to beta test it for you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My own favorite is the free [EssentialPIM](http://www.essentialpim.com/), which has yearly display and much more:

> PIM stands for Personal Information
>   Manager, and it allows you to keep all
>   your information in electronic form.
>   All your appointments, tasks, to do
>   lists, notes, contacts and email
>   messages are stored in a graphical and
>   easily accessible form. Fully Netbook
>   compatible!

[image]

Comment: hallelujah!....

Comment: Does that mean you will be accepting harry's answer so he gets the bounty?

Comment: @Adamv: Almost certainly - I gave him an upvote straight away, but I thought I'd leave it for a couple of days to see what else turned up.

Comment: I've been trying it out for 24 hours... The program is easy to use and visually very clear. Its exactly what I was looking for.